# Will installing Ubuntu using the "erase entire disk" option remove and erase all currently existing partitions?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I'm considering ditching Windows 8 and doing a fully clean install of Ubuntu. However, I'm concerned because my computer came with a built-in 16 GB recovery partition that would need to be erased as well.

If I pick the "erase entire disk" option during installation, will it wipe out this recovery partition too?

Answer (score 5):

Using the "Erase entire disk", will erase all partitions.

Since you're new, I would recommend to start with dual booting with Windows first. Get used to Ubuntu and then you may decide later to remove Windows completely. This is especially recommended if you do not have recovery media or another means of reinstalling Windows should you wish to.

In any case, I would recommend doing a backup of your important data on an external disk before trying to install Ubuntu. If something goes wrong, your data would be safe.

Comment: +1 for backups (even though perhaps < 1% actually do :)

Comment: If I accidentally clicked "Erase entire disk", what can I do to recover my previous partitions? Just after clicking Next with "Erase entire disk" selected, I realized my mistake and didn't go any further. Can my data be saved?

Comment: Your best bet is using testdisk. But stop using it for best chances of success.

Comment: ""Erase entire disk" will erase all partitions." - Will it erase only my first HDD, only my second HDD, any of my HDD or all my HDDs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will.

I've switched from windows 8 to Ubuntu a lot. It will destroy your recovery partition, but it is worth it. SO WORTH IT! You should totally go through with your Ubuntu installation. You will be happy with what you get from it!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Ashton. My only reservation about switching is that I'm a college student and it might be difficult getting homework done and transferring/printing files without the familiar Microsoft programs.

Comment: At most universities, @user183275 is dead right: gotta keep dual boot or be locked out of your classwork.

Comment: If you're referring to MS Office, LibreOffice will read/write/edit/print the same files. Otherwise, if you can't live without your MS programs, you could always see if they will work with WINE.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the option "erase entire disk" option your entire disk partition scheme will be erased and the entire disk space will be alloted to Ubuntu.

To prevent this you can try using "advanced partitioning tool" during formatting.